# How do I add the JJIL libraries to my Android Eclipse project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to use the JJIL libraries with my Android project:
http://code.google.com/p/jjil/

I followed all the instructions on importing libraries into eclipse on the android guides, and have had no successes. It just fails to import.

Can some one point me in the right direction with this?

Cheers,

Nick D

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you download the source and add it to your project. A lot of compiled .jars won't work in Android because they contain stuff that needs to be converted to the Dalvik format. Just download the source from their google code repository and copy it into the /src folder of your project (with the whole com/whatever/whatever/ directory structure, too). The next time you start Eclipse, the source for those libraries should be in your project and building.

Comment: Cool. just fyi, when a post on Stackoverflow solves your problem, you're supposed to mark it as accepted by clicking the little checkmark to the left of it. see the faq(http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.